# How does init() function works in this case

Tags: javascript

Let me introduce this question with short code that I have here:

```
function SomeObject() {
// Personaly I call this part initialization...
this.anything = "anything";

// ... but here somebody call function init...
this.init();
}

// ... which is declared there...
SomeObject.prototype.init = function () {

// ... and contains more initialization. 

}
```

Now here comes the question: 
**What benefits does this implementation of init function have?**

Only benefit that I see is that you can use `init` function on instance later and reinitialize some of its properties and other stuff. But in code that I have, there is no point of doing that. Even more, If I do that, it will break a lot of things. 
Since then, I don't know if is there any difference beside this implementation:

```
function SomeObject() {
    init.call(this);
}

function init() {        
}
```

moreover I don't know any reson why to separate constructor into more parts. So I think (have that feeling) that I really had to miss some important benefit or naturalness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "OOP".

In the second case, you have to use `call` to provide the context, and you have no hint that the function is to be used on instances of `SomeObject`. Of course, the function isn't inherited.

For "private" functions, like this one, it doesn't matter much, especially if it's used only in the constructor (then, is a function really needed ?). But if the function has to be used from other parts of the code, having the function attached to the object which must be the context of the call makes the purpose clearer.

Comment: I can encapsulate SomeObject and init with IIF. Then its easy to recognize that these belongs together. So do you think that should avoid call usage? Or your answer means that it really doesn't matter and it should be solved case by case.

Comment: If `init` is only called from the constructor and you don't have other functions attached to the prototype, it doesn't matter. If you have other functions attached to the prototype, adding this one makes the structure of the code easier to recognize. This being said, I wouldn't recommend to overuse OOP in JavaScript : it tends to be verbose.